# How to write Kotlin code to store all odd numbers starting at 7 till 101 and print sum of them?

Tags: kotlin

How to write Kotlin code to store all odd numbers starting at 7 till 101 and print the sum of them?
My code goes like this:

```kotlin
var sum:Int = 0
var num:Int? = null
for(num in 7..101 )
      if(num % 2 != 0)
         print("$num  ")
      var result = sum + num
       num++
   println("$result")
```

Comment: The question says that you need to _store_ the odd numbers, and _then_ print their sum — but your code doesn't do that.  Is storing the numbers a necessary part?  (If not, then it's almost certainly better not to, as your code and most of the answers demonstrate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply filter the range `7..101` and sum the items:

```
val total = (7..101).filter { it % 2 == 1 }.sum()
println(total)
```

Or use `sumBy()`:

```
val total = (7..101).sumBy { if (it % 2 == 1) it else 0}
println(total)
```

Or first create a list of all the odd numbers and then get the sum:

```
val list = (7..101).filter { it % 2 == 1 }
val total = list.sum()
println(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store them, just create a MutableList and add the odd numbers during the forEach execution

```
var oddNumbersTotal = 0
(7..101).forEach { n ->
  if (n % 2 != 0) {
    oddNumbersTotal += n
  }
}
println(oddNumbersTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
val array = IntArray(48){2*it+1}
print(array.sum())
```